# GUI to take inputs and generate Cron expression for quartz

Tags: .net, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to build a .net GUI or web based GUI which take the inputs like hours,minutes,day and frequency and generate the Cron expression. This will be send to server for setting up the expression through quartz.

Thanks